# host and share files in my hosting

Tags: web-hosting

I currently have a domain+hosting with unlimited hosting space for our website. On the other hand, I use Dropbox to share our organizational files and photos between about 10 users. The thing is that sharing photos uses too much space for what a free Dropbox account offers. So I am thinking of taking advantage of my hosting space, but using FTP seems not to be ideal for users who are not too skilled with computers. In addition, it doesn't handle versions in case some user makes a mess of it. And using a public FTP to upload and giving them only download permission doesn't seem a good idea as I am only the CTO. So what I want is basically to implement a local Dropbox for a few users, but I'd prefer something that is not too complex to install/mantain.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Dropbox has the advantage that it automatically downloads/synchronises with a local folder on their PC. Presumably this is something that you don't require?

Comment: You can always map FTP sites as network drives in (Windows?) using their login as such: `ftp://user:pass@host.com:21/` and still implement certain permissions.

Comment: The problem with Dropbox is that the space is not enough for hosting hundreds of photos (not enough space).

Mapping FTP as a network drive sound interesting... What are those permissions that can be implemented? How can I make sure that if a user deletes something I can restore it?

Comment: Setup your own Dropbox on your hosting: http://owncloud.org/ It's free!

Answer (score 0):

**Check with the terms of service of your host.**

Most unlimited hosting services have clauses to prevent abuse. It is often specified that you can only host files used for your websites and not for personal storage.

On the other hand, for a service with fixed hosting space, you are usually allowed to use the space with fewer restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe owncloud is what you are looking for. There are clients for android, windows, mac, linux and (I think) iOS. It's running on PHP and can be easily installed.

Answer (score -1):

There are file sharing application you can run on your hosting account to do photo/file sharing. But i am not sure if your hosting company allows it.

Comment: What software are you using? I have seen Microsoft SharePoint and sounds perfect, but I cannot install it on my hosting. Other ideas?